# To what general class does onomatopoeia belong?

Tags: semiotics, onomatopoeia

Onomatopoeia is a word (⊂ signs) whose vocal representation mimics the sound the word describes.

Are there signs whose

1. visual/written representation mimics the visual appearance the word describes? (Pictogram?)
2. tactile representation mimics the feel the word describes?
3. olfactory representation mimics the smell the word describes?
4. gustatory representation mimics the taste the word describes?

To what general class do these words belong?

Comment: Don't you yourself answer your own question by saying, “Onomatopoeia is a word”?

Comment: @YellowSky That's too general a class/genus. I'm looking for the proximate genus.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by a "general class". Class of what? Defined how?

Comment: (2), (3), and (4) are absurd, and the only example I can think of for (1) is ***O***

Comment: @jlawler What makes them absurd?

Comment: Words have only aural and oral (long-distance sense) representations. There are no tactile, gustatory, or olfactory "words". So you can't just substitute senses and make any sense.

Comment: @jlawler Braille words are tactile words.

Comment: Braille is just a version of English spelling with tactile sense. Not different from ABC. An office I go to regularly puts braille messages on their wall video display (!), showing that they think of it as writing.

Comment: @jlawler Yes, different signs can signify the same word.

Comment: @jlawler in sign languages words are visual. Contact sign languages have tactile words. There's also no reason there might not be some species with olfactory words

Answer (score 3):

Onomatopoeia are instances of [sound symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism), which is a type of [iconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconicity).

Sound symbolism is broader than onomatopoeia; it also covers, for example, the use of reduplication for the expression of plurality, the fact that words for "tongue" often contain lateral consonants, or the [bouba/kiki effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect).

Comment: Or the [English KL- words](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf). Note that many of these words refer to sounds, but they're the same kind of sounds, all produced by impacts. This is part of the semantic theme of _together_. Generally, when assonances or rimes have sound-symbolic meanings, they will include an audial set, as here. There is often a large pejorative subset, though not on KL-.